# Precision in the placement of Brackets

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to make so that the brackets are positioned exactly on the coordinates of the points (a) and (b)?

```
    \documentclass[6pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{angles,backgrounds,calc,arrows.meta,
                    decorations.pathreplacing,intersections,
                    patterns,positioning,quotes}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,>=stealth,x=2cm]

    \coordinate (a) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (3,0);
    \draw(-0.5,0)--(4.5 ,0);
    \foreach \x/\xtext in {0/,1/7.4,2/7.5,3/7.6,4/}
    \draw(\x,2pt)--(\x,-2pt) node[below] {\xtext};
    \draw[<->,red, thick] (1,10pt) -- node[above]{0,1} (2,10pt);
    \draw[<->,red, thick] (2,10pt) -- node[above]{0,1} (3,10pt);
    \draw[Bracket-Bracket,ultra thick,red](a) -- (b);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The reason this happens is that by default, arrows are designed to end exactly at the coordinate.  So the bracket is placed so that its edge is at the specified coordinate.  You want the coordinate to be in the middle of the vertical line so you need to push it half a linewidth over.  Zarko's answer shows how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for these very clear explanations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can with `shorten ...=-0.5\pgflinewidth` increase length of red line:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=6pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,>=stealth,x=2cm]

\coordinate (a) at (1,0);
\coordinate (b) at (3,0);
\draw(-0.5,0)--(4.5 ,0);
\foreach \x/\xtext in {0/,1/7.4,2/7.5,3/7.6,4/}
\draw(\x,2pt)--(\x,-2pt) node[below] {\xtext};
\draw[<->,red, thick] (1,10pt) -- node[above]{0,1} (2,10pt);
\draw[<->,red, thick] (2,10pt) -- node[above]{0,1} (3,10pt);
\draw[Bracket-Bracket,ultra thick,red, semitransparent,% in real document remove "semitransparent"
      shorten <=-0.5\pgflinewidth, shorten >=-0.5\pgflinewidth] (a) -- (b); % <---

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
You can define for each combination of prackets own style:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=6pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,>=stealth,x=2cm,
 B/.style = {Bracket-Bracket, 
             draw=red, ultra thick,
             shorten <=-0.5\pgflinewidth, shorten >=-0.5\pgflinewidth},
BL/.style = {{Bracket[reversed]}-Bracket,
             draw=red, ultra thick,
             shorten <=-1.5\pgflinewidth, shorten >=-0.5\pgflinewidth},
BR/.style = {Bracket-{Bracket[reversed]},
             draw=red, ultra thick,
             shorten <=-0.5\pgflinewidth, shorten >=-1.5\pgflinewidth},
Br/.style = {{Bracket[reversed]}-{Bracket[reversed]},
             draw=red, ultra thick,
             shorten <=-1.5\pgflinewidth, shorten >=-1.5\pgflinewidth}
                    ]
\coordinate (a) at (1,0);
\coordinate (b) at (3,0);
\draw(-0.5,0)--(4.5 ,0);
\foreach \x/\xtext in {0/,1/7.4,2/7.5,3/7.6,4/}
\draw(\x,2pt)--(\x,-2pt) node[below] {\xtext};
\draw[<->,red, thick] (1,10pt) -- node[above]{0,1} (2,10pt);
\draw[<->,red, thick] (2,10pt) -- node[above]{0,1} (3,10pt);
\draw[B]  (a) -- (b); % <---
\draw[BL] ([yshift=-8mm] a) -- ([yshift=-8mm] b); % <---
\draw[BR] ([yshift=-12mm] a) -- ([yshift=-12mm] b); % <---
\draw[Br] ([yshift=-16mm] a) -- ([yshift=-16mm] b); % <---
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this solution. The idea now is to write a robust macro which allows you to choose the points (a) and (b) as well as the shape of the brackets (opening or closing).

Comment: @Fabrice, for writing macro (if it is really needed) you should ask a new question. To my opinion a style for common features of this interval should be suffucient.

Comment: It's ok. Another question if you agree well : how to have  ]         ] ?

Comment: @Fabrice, see addendum in my answer.

Comment: Nice work, thank you very much. I read in the documentation that it was necessary to use the key reversed but I did not know that it was necessary to write `{Bracket[reversed]}` instead of `Bracket[reversed]`.