# I can't get latex(tikz) to draw a right square bracket

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am a beginner so please forgive any obvious mistakes. When using the code below

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[latex-latex] (-3,0) -- (8,0) ; %edit here for the axis
\foreach \x in  {-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} % edit here for the vertical lines
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);
\foreach \x in {-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} % edit here for the numbers
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] 
{$\x$};
**\draw[very thick][([-]] (0,0) -- (2*pi,0);**
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I can't get latex to draw the closed(right) square  bracket. it draws the left one just fine. It also draws the left and right curved brackets with no problems. I am trying to show the range of a set on a number line. The line of code with the set of double asterisks is where the error occurs.

```
\draw[very thick][([-)] (0,0) -- (2*pi,0)
```

the line above works just fine as replacement so this indicates the use of square brackets itself is not the main problem.

```
\draw[very thick][((-)] (0,0) -- (2*pi,0)
```

and two curved brackets work just fine as well but putting in a square bracket to close off the line does not. an explanation or solution would be lovely.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To long for the comment ...

Do you like to have the following image:

[image]

It is drawn by use `arrows.meta` TikZ library:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% <---

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[latex-latex] (-3,0) -- (8,0) ; %edit here for the axis
\foreach \x in  {-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} % edit here for the vertical lines
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);
\foreach \x in {-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} % edit here for the numbers
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below]
{$\x$};
\draw[very thick,Bracket-Bracket] (0,0) -- (2*pi,0); % <---
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For details see documentation for *Tikz & PGFManual* section *Reference: Arrow Tips*. There are lised other arrows heads tips.

**Addendum:**
Off-topic remark. Your code for image can be shorter, with only one loop. Also in testing of some images code, the use of the `standalone` document class instead for example `article` can be handy. It will show only image:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone} % will show only diagram, not whole page
%\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
%\usepackage{tikz}                           % use at other document classes
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[latex-latex] (-3,0) -- (8,0); 
\foreach \x in  {-1,0,...,7}
{
\draw (\x,3pt) -- ++ (0,-6pt) node[below] {$\x$};
}
\draw[very thick,Bracket-Bracket] (0,0) -- (2*pi,0); % <---
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which will show only your image:

[image]

**Note:** For other types of function ranges see answer [marking function ranges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560713/precision-in-the-placement-of-brackets/560727#560727).

Comment: Thanks a lot exactly what I wanted

Comment: @JimDanger, Thanks on this site are normally given via upvotes (when you will have enough reputation).   You may not be aware of this. If an answer answer solve your problem on the best way (toyour opinion), you can accept it by clicking on check mark at top left side of (selected) answer.